# A men's endurance competition has an unlimited number of rounds

Tags: probability

> A men's endurance competition has an unlimited number of rounds. In each round, a competitor has, independently, a probability p of making it through the round; otherwise, he fails the round. Once a competitor fails a round, he drops out the competition; before he drops out, he takes part in every round. The grand prize is awarded to any competitor who makes it through a round which all the other remaining competitors fail; if all the remaining competitors fail at the same round the grand prize is not awarded. If the competition begins with three competitors, show that the probability that the grand prize is awarded is $\frac{3p(1+p^2)}{(1+p)(1+p+p^2)}$

I have an attempt at the problem which I am pretty convinced by and gives a similar answer, but not correct. I would like to know where my reasoning goes wrong

Suppose we number each player P1,P2,P3. We will find the probability P3 wins the grand prize and by symmetry that is the same for all of them.

P(P3 wins on the rth round) = $2\choose1$ P(A player fails on the rth round) * P(A player fails before or on the rth round) * P(A player passes r rounds)

The choose permutes P1 and P2. I.e. P1 could fail on the rth and P2 before, or vice versa.

P(A player fails on the rth round) $=p^{r-1}(1-p)$

P(A player passes r rounds) $=p^r$

P(A player fails on or before the rth round $=1-p^r$

So now, we want to sum from $r=1$ to infinity. We multiply by three to perform this for each player.

$$P(\text{Grand prize awarded})=\sum_{r=1}^\infty 6p^{2r-1}(1-p)(1-p^r)=\frac{6p}{(p+1)(p^2+p+1)}$$

Comment: The first calculation, where you multiply by $\binom21$ is wrong, I think.  It's okay to multiply the probability that A fails on round $r$ and B fails before round $r$ by $2$, but you're also multiplying the probability that both fail on round $r$ by $2$, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @saulspatz Haha, that reallly was it! If I subtract, from that line, P(Both fail on rth round)*P(A player passes r rounds), the answer falls out. Thanks, missing that inclusion-exclusion was sloppy of me.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Note that we must have $p<1$.  When $p=1$, it says that the the probability that the prize is awarded is $1$, but everyone succeeds on every round, so the prize is never awarded.  Probably, you assumed $p<1$ when summing the series.

Comment: @saulspatz In the calculations, I cancelled out (p-1)/(p-1). If you feel like putting all this in an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first calculation, where you multiply by $\binom21$ is wrong, I think. It's okay to multiply the probability that A fails on round $r$ and B fails before round $r$ by $2$, but you're also multiplying the probability that both fail on round $r$ by $2$, if I understand you correctly.

As noted in the comments, the answer is only valid for $0\leq p<1$.